# How to handle divide by 0

Tags: java, android, try-catch

```
if (getOperator=="/"){
    try {
        sum = value1/value2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        summaryTxt.setText("Invalid operation");
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but you should never compare strings with ==. Use Equals instead. == is for comparing memory references. Also either your use a getter name getOperator and your are missing (), or your should use a better name (like operator).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is wrong, and this is a bad practise.

Imagine, that value1 can be Integer and it is null. Then you will catch a NullPointerException, but your code will tell you that the operation is invalid, but it is not.

Exceptions are not for checking conditions. Better to check them explicitly:

```
     if (getOperator=="/"){
        if (value2 == 0) {
           summaryTxt.setText("Value2 can't be 0!");
        } else {
           sum = value1/value2;
        }
      }
```

Comment: +1: Exceptions should never be used for flow control, especially when simple `if-else` checks suffice.  @user655443: If it doesn't display that message, then `value2` is not zero.  And hence there won't be a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: I try if (getOperator=="/"){
      {
             if (value2 == 0) {
              Log.d("test", "eeee");
                summaryTxt.setText(""+"Value2 can't be 0!");
             } else {
                sum = value1/value2;
             }
           }
     }

Comment: and It show "eeee" in Logcat when value2=0 but it doesn't show "Value2 can't be 0!"

Comment: Then it is unrelated problem. Ask another question and show more code: how do you define summaryTxt, where this code executes and so on.

Comment: On a side note, caching exception should be faster than using a if each time you want to divide. But just by reading the code and context, the impact would be negligible. This is just to include one raison among other somebody would prefer catching the Arithmetic error.

Comment: @Nicolas, throwing an exception is one of the most slow operation in java. And if is just 2 asm instructions: cmp and jmp.

Comment: Yes this is damn slow. But it is supposed to be exceptional. If you expect your program to have lot of invalid entries then a if will be faster. if it is really exceptionnal, or just a bug, the exception will be faster as it don't cost anything when you don't divide by 0.

Answer (score 3):

Division by zero will throw an ArithmeticException if the values are e.g. integers, so that's what you should catch.

Performing division by zero using doubles will instead give a result that is Double.Infinity

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to handle division by **Zero** and **NaN**:

```
public static double safeDivide(double dividend, double divisor) {
    if(Double.compare(divisor, Double.NaN) == 0) return Double.NaN;
    if(Double.compare(dividend, Double.NaN) == 0) return Double.NaN;
    if(Double.compare(divisor, 0.0) == 0) {
        if(Double.compare(dividend, 0.0) == -1) {
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    if(Double.compare(divisor, -0.0) == 0) {
        if(Double.compare(dividend, -0.0) == 1) {
            return Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        }
        return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }
    return dividend / divisor;
}
```

> **Reference:**
>
> **math.stackexchange** >> [I have learned that 1/0 is infinity, why isn't it minus infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127402)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this by catching the exception then:

```
if (getOperator == "/") {
    try {
        sum = value1 / value2;
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        summaryTxt.setText("Invalid operation: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Catching `Exception` is definitely a bad idea in general, if not in this specific instance.  The problem is that there is a good chance that you will catch other kinds of exception that you (the programmer) did not anticipate; e.g. a NullPointerException in this case if the type of `value1` or `value2` is a primitive wrapper class and the value is `null`.

It is also debatable whether you should implement this using exceptions or by testing for zero explicitly.  IMO, **either way is acceptable** here.  Division by zero will most likely be a rare occurrence for this code, and the rule is you should only use exceptions in exceptional situations.  (You don't have to, but you can ...)

However, I think I'd use an explicit test, on the grounds that it makes the code easier to read.

```
if (getOperator == "/") {
    if (value2 != 0) {
        sum = value1 / value2;
    } else {
        summaryTxt.setText("Invalid operation: divide by zero");
    }
}
```

(Aside: `getOperator == "/"` is dodgy unless your code *guarantees* that getOperator always contains an intern'ed String ...)

Answer (score 2):

write an extension function like this

```
    Double.safeDiv(other:Number,fallback:Double):Double {
       if(other == 0)
          return fallback
       else 
          return this / other
   }
```

where fallback is the value you want to return when divider is 0

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check if 
Value2.equals(0);
And throw your own exception if so

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getOperator=="/" && value2 == 0){
    summaryTxt.setText("Value2 can't be 0!");
}else if(getOperator=="/" && != 0){
    sum = value1/value2;
}
```

so beautiful code)